# How to map values of a Django model column to a list?

Tags: python, django, models

I'm just getting started in Django development, and I'm trying to dynamically populated a ChoiceField() class with options from a column of DB entries of another model.

This is the way I'm approaching the situation currently:

```
categories_as_choices = map(lambda x: x.mycolumnname, MyObjectCategory.objects.all())
```

I'm not really sure if this is the most "pythonic" approach (or the Django equivalent). Does anyone know if there's a "better" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides a field class specifically designed for this: [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

You'll need to define `__unicode__` method on your category model like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.mycolumnname
```

And then in the form you can simply use

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyObjectCategory.objects.all())
```